# A working project in CodeBlocks cannot be run outside CodeBlocks

Tags: windows, codeblocks, sfml

I have a working project written in C++ in Windows 7, CodeBlocks13.12 but that does not work outside of CodeBlocks. The code compiles and runs as expected in the CodeBlocks IDE. I built the code for Debug and Release environment. The CodeBlocks generates an executable file called `RescueMissionGame.exe` in my case. I repeat that when I am building and running the project in CodeBlocks, everything works perfectly well.

When I try to run this executable file outside of CodeBlocks,the application asks me to install `openal32.dll` and `libsndfile-1.dll`.I put those files in the directory of the `.exe`. As a result, when I execute `RescueMissionGame.exe` the applications starts but immediatly after that shuts down(which is not the case in CodeBlocks).

My Project is composed of 5 classes and a `main.cpp`. Also, I use SFML2.0 library for the project.

Can you give me any advice what to do to be able to execute the project outside CodeBlocks?
Thank you!

EDIT:
Here is the `main.cpp` code:

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));

    try
    {
        Game game;
        game.run();
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `int main()` code?  In Codeblocks, the debugger will prevent the application from escaping too early on you.

Comment: Are you using any kind of application loop?

Comment: The main.cpp code is in edit of the question. What do you mean by application loop?

Comment: Add `cin.get()` before the `return`, recompile and run the application outside of Codeblocks.  Also, make sure you have the project set to Console project (not GUI Application) for all build configurations in Project->Properties->Build.

Comment: A runtime exception could be getting thrown that you are not able to see outside Codeblocks but the application dies too quickly for you to see it.

Comment: AND catch `std::exception` instead of `runtime_error`

Comment: Ok, making these changes seems to have solved the issue. However, right now my application tells me that it cannot load an image despite that in CodeBlocks there is no problem with loading images(the images). I suppose I'd better ask in a different tpoic what may cause the new problem.

Comment: Can you explain what does the 'cin.get()' do? I can't understand why I should use it.

Comment: Yes.  Make sure you provide as much code as you possibly can to ensure you receive a valid and prompt answer.

Comment: `cin.get()` will make the console input stream to wait for the user to hit the return key before allowing the thread to continue execution.  It also returns the contents of the input buffer stream.